# Installing a TOPGREENER 3 way smart dimmer switch

Tags: smart-switch

Need some help as I try to install a Top Greener 3 way smart dimmer switch.

In the first box, there are three relevant wires.

Bundle 1: Contains the Hot wire.
Black: connects to my switch;
White: connects to the group neutral.

Bundle 2: Contains black and white wires
Black: connects to the black wire in the 3rd bundle
White: Connects to the Neutral group

Bundle 3: Contains black, white, and red wires
Black: Connects to black wire in 2nd bundle
White: ...
Red:...

[image]

In the 2nd box, there is only one bundle coming in and my second “add-on switch”.
My issue is that this add-on switch only has connections for travellers and neutral.
Bundle 1: Contains black, white, and red wires
I only have two connection slots for travellers, none for the load, but I have three incoming wires.

[image]
I believe I have a unique situation wherein the wire to the light is a direct link in the first box and the 2nd box is simply there as a remote trigger. It is my understanding that Buindle 1 is the power source, Bundle 2 goes to the light fixture, and bundle 3 goes to the second box.
Can someone steer my in right direction with how I wire Bundle 3 in the first box and Bundle 1 in the second box. I have one too many wires for my knowledge.
Thanks,

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a diagram of your expected wiring? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Wider pictures that show how the current light switches are hooked up would be great.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual dimmer switch you're trying to use, or better yet, to its instruction sheet?

Answer (score 1):

### Totally divide unrelated circuits

That second box really ought to have a divider in it.  There are two totally separate circuits in there, and they mustn't mix.  As photographed, it appears the switch wired into the /3 cable is stealing a neutral from the other circult. *that's exactly what you must not do*.

Now, safety ground wires (bare or green) are allowed to cross-connect. That is fine.

### Junk or real?

This is yet another "Sold by XXX and Fulfilled by Amazon", which is the hallmark of *Amazon Marketplace*, Amazon's worse-than-eBay flea-market.  The vast, vast majority of those are dangerous junk from China.  *This one claims to have a UL listing; yeah right*.  Examine it carefully for the familiar UL logo, with a C *and/or* US mark, and also for a 6-8 digit *file number*.   Like this

[image]

If the mark isn't proper like that, Back to Amazon it goes.  And don't buy electrical gear from *Amazon Marketplace* anymore.

### How to wire it, though

The smarter of the 2 switches needs to be at the primary (first) junction box with the 3 cables.  That's where you can find always-hot, neutral, switched-hot (for LOAD).

The dumber of the 2 switches goes at the secondary box (the one where only the /3 cable goes) and it touches only the /3 cable.

You will need to re-task (move around) the wires in the connecting /3 cable.

- White becomes neutral (it wasn't before) and must be connected to the neutrals in the primary box.
- Black becomes the one traveler.
- It appears to me red is not used. That needs to be safely capped off. Do not cut the wires off - you may need them for the next smart switch after this one fails or becomes obsolete.

Comment: The last Topgreener thingy I ran into was actually an Enerlites thingy (which is proper stuff)...need a product link to sort out the origins of this one though

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Given the moronic ESL name, I assumed topgreener is one of those Chinese companies like Sonoff who (maybe) is trying to make good by working with UL.